# Change Image onClick and onRelease?

Tags: html, css

Is there a possibility to change the buttons image to button_pressed.png while the button is pressed and change it back to button_unpressed.png when the button is released again?

**EDIT**

I have the following HTML:

```
<header id="toolbar">
    <div id="toolbar_back">
        <form action="#/">
            <input type="image" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <h1 id="toolbar_title">Photo Prints</h1>
</header>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#toolbar {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #888888;
    display: table;
}

#toolbar_title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#toolbar_back {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#toolbar_back input {
    background: url("../img/toolbar/toolbar_back.png");
}

#toolbar_back input:active {
    background: url("../img/toolbar/toolbar_back_pressed.png");
}
```

But with this the result is the following:

[image]

I just want the background images to be shown and i want them to be fully shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to make the button a background image:

```
#button input {
    background-image: url("img/button_unpressed.png");
    background-size: cover; /* or 'contain' */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#button input:active,
#button input:focus {
    background-image: url("img/button_pressed.png");
}
```

You'll probably also need to remove border and other styles to only show your background image.

Comment: I updated my post. Your solution sounds good but it leeded to a weird result.

Comment: Updated with some more specific CSS.

Comment: ok i got that. looks like it should now. but the background image isnt changing on click. it stays the same image always.